# How can I create variable or function names in Python by concatenating strings?

Tags: python, variables

For instance, I want to type `country0 = code0 + 'abc'` and then do the same thing for all integers from 0 to 9.

However, the following snippet obviously doesn't work:

```
for i in range(10):
  country + i = code + i + 'abc'
```

So, what can be done instead? Your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?  The proper way to handle a series of related items is as a single list (or other container) - `country[i] = code[i] + 'abc'`.

Comment: Create the string "country0 = code0 + 'abc'" and pass it to exec().

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  As a beginner, you should never, never, never use exec().  You are creating a major security hole.  Use an array as suggested by @jasonharper